# Looping through array of Arrays with Recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am trying to solve this problem with recursion because I want to make my life worse. I am taking an array of arrays and returning one array with all of the values. It is so close to working but the new array I am pushing to keeps reseting after every recursion. Can I get some advice?

```
var myArray = [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]

const flatten = function (arr) {
  let output = [];

  arr.map(element => {
    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      console.log('Is Array ---> ', element)
      flatten(element);
    } else {
      console.log('Output ----->', output)
      console.log('Else     --->', element)
      output.push(element);
    }

  });

  return output;

};

console.log('Retrun ----->', flatten(myArray)); //[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Comment: Inside your `map`, you call `flatten` but you never use the result. Also, using a `map` but not using its return value can be misleading. `forEach` may be more appropriate

Comment: It is not what you are currently asking but just in case if you are not aware, there is such function : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: Yes thanks! I looked this one up but I wanted to figure it out with recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You should push the results of calling `flatten(element)` using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Rest_syntax_parameters):

```
output.push(...flatten(element));
```

Note: you should also replace the map call with `Array.forEach()`, since you don't use the returned array.

**Example:**

```js
const flatten = function(arr) {
  const output = [];

  arr.forEach(element => {
    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      output.push(...flatten(element));
    } else {
      output.push(element);
    }

  });

  return output;

};

var myArray = [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]


console.log(flatten(myArray)); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have not come across the `...` before. I had been using forEach and then switched to .map() trying anything to figure it out. Appreciate the help!

Comment: The `...` are called the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Rest_syntax_parameters).

Answer (score 1):

If your nested arrays can't have nested arrays themselves there should be no need for recursion:

[`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) gives you a simple way to flatten such arrays:

> The flatMap() method first maps each element using a mapping function, then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a map() followed by a flat() of depth 1, but flatMap() is often quite useful, as merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.

Example:

```js
[[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]].flatMap(xs => xs);
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And in case you have deeply nested arrays such as

```js
[[1, 2, [3, 4, 5, [6, 7, 8, 9]]]]
```

Then a recursive `flatMap` is still the best option IMHO:

```js
const flatten = xs =>
  xs.flatMap(x =>
    Array.isArray(x)
      ? flatten(x)
      : x);

flatten([[1, 2, [3, 4, 5, [6, 7, 8, 9]]]]);
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Of course this is all obsolete with [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) which can unnest deeply nested arrays:

> The flat() method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

If you don't know the depth just set it to Infinity:

```js
[[1, 2, [3, 4, 5, [6, 7, 8, 9]]]].flat(Infinity);
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

However it's worth noting that `flat` isn't supported across most modern browsers yet. If you can afford Babel in your project then there isn't much reason not to use it.

---

While you *can* build your own recursive function, it is also worth considering the native options the language has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this

```
var myArray = [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
const flatten = (element, acc = []) => {
   if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      element.forEach(subelement => {
         flatten(subelement, acc)
      })
   } else {
      acc.push(element)
   }
   return acc
}
console.log(flatten(myArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]

function flatten (arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, element) => {
    if (Array.isArray(element)) return [...acc, ...flatten(element)];
    acc.push(element);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(flatten(myArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to do without using any 'magic':

```js
function flatten(input,output){
  if(!output)
    output=[];
  if(!Array.isArray(input))
    output.push(input);
  else
    for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++)
      flatten(input[i],output);
  return output;
}

var test = [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], 6, [[7, 8], 9]];
console.log(flatten(test).join());
```

I think this would be the classic, school-level recursive approach.

The particular issue in your code is the recursive call: `flatten(element);`. The function does not get the partial result, `output` (as in the code above, there is an 'optional' argument which is initialized to `[]` when it is missing), and whatever it returns does not get appended to the existing output either.

Any of the two would work:

```js
var myArray = [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]

const flatten = function (arr, output) { // added output
  if(!output)                            // initializing if missing
    output = [];

  arr.map(element => {
    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      console.log('Is Array ---> ', element.join())
      flatten(element, output);          // added output
    } else {
      console.log('Output ----->', output.join())
      console.log('Else     --->', element)
      output.push(element);
    }

  });

  return output;

};

console.log('Return ----->', flatten(myArray).join()); //[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

(Added some `.join()`s too, so the log is horizontal)

Or the second fix:

```js
var myArray = [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]

const flatten = function (arr) {
  let output = [];

  arr.map(element => {
    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      console.log('Is Array ---> ', element.join())
      output = output.concat(flatten(element));     // concatenate with result
    } else {
      console.log('Output ----->', output.join())
      console.log('Else     --->', element)
      output.push(element);
    }

  });

  return output;

};

console.log('Return ----->', flatten(myArray).join()); //[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```